# Parse XML file that has unique elements with ajax

Tags: ajax, xml

I am currently trying to parse and xml file that is of the following format:

```
<holidays>
    <holiday1> text </holiday1>
    <holiday2> text </holiday2>
    <holiday3> text </holiday3>
    <holiday4> text </holiday4>
    ...
```

with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<filename>',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: xmlParser
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
  $('#load').fadeOut();
  $(xml).contents().each(function () {
    $("#holidates").append('<p>' + $(this).text() + '</p>');  
  });
  $(".dates").fadeIn(2000);
}
```

The current output is:

```
<p>01/13/2016 02/02/2016 12/24/2015 12/24/2015 12/24/2015 12/29/2015 12/30/2015 11/23/2015 01/01/2016 01/26/2016 12/25/2015</p>
```

I would prefer:

```
<p>01/13/2016</p>
<p>02/02/2016</p>
<p>12/24/2015</p>
....
```

Is there a way to achieve his without formatting the xml file?  The file is part of another system and is required in the indicated format.

Many thanks.

Comment: The xml file is not consistent with the ajax output. Is the 'text' supposed to be the dates?

Comment: sorry, yes the 'text' is the dates so would read as:
<holidays>
<holiday1>01/13/2016</holiday1>
<holiday2>02/02/2016</holiday2>
<holiday3>12/24/2015</holiday3>
....

Answer (score 0):

Given your feedback, the problem is clear. You take the text value of the root element. This however just concatenates all text elements from its children.

I am not a pro when it comes to ajax, but the idea is to select the 'holiday' tags and run an 'each' on that set.

Your XML structure makes it a bit harder than it should be because of the integers in the name. If you are certain that all the children of the 'holidays' tag are 'holidayx' tags then you could just take all children.

```
$(xml).contents().find('holidays').children().each(function () {
    $("#holidates").append('<p>' + $(this).text() + '</p>');  
});
```

I would suggest trying something like that.